# ¿Se puede en hacer más de una operación cuando np.where es True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos `DataFrame` y luego necesito hacer varias operaciones entre ambos. Mi consulta es, si hay alguna manera de no repetir la sentencia y ejecutar 2 o más operaciones cuando entra por el `True`.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sku':['A1','A2','A3'],
                    'stock':[90,50,30],
                    'fecha':[datetime.date(2019, 7, 21),datetime.date(2019, 7, 10),datetime.date(2019, 7, 1)]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sku':['A1','A2','A3'],
                    'stock':[55,99,31],
                    'fecha':[datetime.date(2019, 7, 31),datetime.date(2019, 7, 15),datetime.date(2019, 7, 5)]
                   })



df2["dif"] = np.where(df2['stock'] > df1['stock'],
                      df2['stock'] - df1['stock'],0)

df2["tmstp"] = np.where(df2['stock'] > df1['stock'],
                        df2['fecha']- df1['fecha'],
                        0)
```

Como está en el ejemplo funciona bien, pero mi duda es si se puede hacer un solo `where` y varias operaciones, ya que en el `df` real debo hacer mas de 2 operaciones.

Comment: Hola Lucas, no se si tengo claro lo que buscas ¿quieres saber si es posible unir ambos np.where y que se generen de una vez "dif" y "tmstp"? ¿O lo que quieres es ademas de la resta hacer otra operación?

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla , viste en el np.where , hago la misma pregunta, o sea si df2.stock > df1.stock. hago dos operaciones. si entendí bien, la primer pregunta que me hiciste sería lo que busco. o sea si pasa tal condición, creo la columna "dif" y "tmstp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, creo que te preocupa el hecho de repetir la operación de condicion sobre `df2['stock'] > df1['stock']` dado que quieres 2 o más comportamientos en el caso de que se cumpla esa condición.

Mi primera observación, es que el calculo de esta condición se puede asignar a una variable, para evitar calcularla múltiples veces (aunque es probable que el scheduler de Python cachee el primer calculo de esa sentencia y en las siguientes llamadas utilice este mismo valor. Por lo que no deberías preocuparte de la eficiencia de este calculo, aunque te recomiendo asignarla a una variable para asegurarte.

Te devuelvo la pregunta consultando ¿Que es lo que te preocupa exactamente: La eficiencia o la cantidad de lineas?

Yendo al grano, no puedes asignar valores a multiples columnas de un DataFrame en 1 sentencia, sin embargo, no deberías preocuparte por ineficiencias en esta asignación.
El where podrías reducirlo para que se haga en una sentencia y luego hacer la asignación al DF, como te muestro a continuación.

Si tu objetivo real es reducir la cantidad de lineas y mantener buena eficiencia lo que puedes hacer Pythonicamente es:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sku':['A1','A2','A3'],
                    'stock':[90,50,30],
                    'fecha':[datetime.date(2019, 7, 21),datetime.date(2019, 7, 10),datetime.date(2019, 7, 1)]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sku':['A1','A2','A3'],
                    'stock':[55,99,31],
                    'fecha':[datetime.date(2019, 7, 31),datetime.date(2019, 7, 15),datetime.date(2019, 7, 5)]
                   })


mask = df2['stock'] > df1['stock']
condition = np.where(mask, [df2['stock'] - df1['stock'], df2['fecha']- df1['fecha']], 0)
df2["dif"],  df2["tmstp"]= condition[0], condition[1]
```

Comment: Me tiraba TypeError cuando haces  `df2['fecha'] - df1['fecha']` , y le agregue  `.values` . Por si no se entendió, preguntaba para no repetir el mismo `np.where` varias veces,